# Application fails to read strings from localized folders

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, resources, translation

I got a strange case going on. My app has 4 language supports: English, Turkish, Russian & Ukrainian. I got the following resource folders:

[image: Resources Screenshot]

I got Turkish translation on values, so default will be Turkish if it fails to find the translation of any string.

Below you can see there are no keys needing translation:

[image: Translation Screenshot]

Okay so, as far as I know, when I change the phone language, it should use corresponding strings.

When I make phone language Turkish:

[image: Turkish Screenshot]

Great. Now, English:

[image: English Screenshot]

Works too. Now Russian:

[image: Turkish Screenshot]

Ugh.

So Turkish and English are working, but making phone language Russian or Ukrainian does not.

There is no manual setting for locale anywhere in the app. When I call

```
getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

or

```
getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales()
```

I get correct locale, "ru_RU".

Is there something I'm missing here ? What might cause this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, it was resConfigs in build.gradle. My config was

```
resConfigs "en", "tr"
```

so it was not compiling ru & uk resources. Adding "ru" & "uk" solved the problem. Final line looks like this:

```
resConfigs "en", "tr", "ru", "uk"
```